# Problem hosting from a wifi hotspot on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, routes, hosting, hotspot

I'm in a village with no Internet. I want to self host Mumble and an HLS server and spread WIFI at the same time. Both of those services work fine when hosting inside a WLAN - when being a wifi client. However, when I set up a hotspot off my laptop and try that, it doesn't work. The IP of the laptop hotspot is 10.42.0.1 and smartphones, etc, can connect to it. 
Whenever I try to connect to the actual services though, the connection is refused.

All services are hosting on 0.0.0.0.
The hotspot was set up from GUI on Manjaro Linux. 
Currently I've got ip forwarding on as well as this iptables entry:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
I'm using docker to run the thing:
docker run --rm -it --shm-size=256m -p 1935:1935 -p 8080:8080 --name streamer streamer

Any ides how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest this is not a really technical answer. 
HOWEVER, after trying the built in Manjaro OS GUI, I decided to go command line. The "hostapd" was probably the perfect solution. But instead I used the https://github.com/oblique/create_ap wrapper and it worked like a charm. It was simple and concise. My guess is, the GUI setup was not working as intended.

```
#create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

worked just fine.